# get multiple select options and add them one by one separately in a normal select

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to get multiple options on a multiple select and add them in a normal select but when i click on a button to add, for exemple, i select on two options and add them they change to one option on the normal select

JSFIDDLE [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0b0obyra/3)

JavaScript CODE

```
function addProf() {
    // get reference to select element
    var sel = document.getElementById('ProfAdd');
    var opt = document.createElement('option'); // create new option element
    // create text node to add to option element (opt)
    if ($(this).find('option[value="' + sel + '"]').length == 0) {
        opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('selProf').value));
        opt.value = 'option val'; // set value property of opt
        sel.appendChild(opt); // add opt to end of select box (sel)
        $("#selProf").find('option:selected').remove();
    }

}

function remProf() {
    // get reference to select element
    var sel = document.getElementById('selProf');
    var opt = document.createElement('option'); // create new option element
    // create text node to add to option element (opt)
    if ($(this).find('option[value="' + sel + '"]').length == 0) {
        opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('ProfAdd').value));
        opt.value = $("#ProfAdd :selected").text(); // set value property of opt
        opt.text = $("#ProfAdd :selected").text();
        sel.appendChild(opt); // add opt to end of select box (sel)
        $("#ProfAdd").find('option:selected').remove();
    }

}
```

HTML CODE

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputProf">Adicionar professores à turma</label>
    <select id="selProf" class="form-control" required>
        <option disabled selected>Professor</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="button" id="button6" class="myButton2" onclick="addProf()" value="Adicionar Professor">
</br>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="InputTurma">Professores adicionados</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="ProfAdd">
    </select>
</div>
<input type="button" id="button7" class="myButton2" onclick="remProf()" value="Retirar Professor">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [ask] with [mcve] The code is not enough to understand and reproduce the problem. Add HTML code too, also add a jsfiddle/codepen demo if possible

Comment: this http://jsfiddle.net/0b0obyra/3/ works (you forgot to include jquery and you have to bind the clicks differently in jsfiddle), but I´m not sure what is your goal? It seems to work just fine.

Comment: in the multiple select when i select more then 1 option and remove in the other select the options bind together and i want it seperatly

Comment: the problem is that u don't use an each function so you get every select option you get them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two options selected, `$('select :selected').text()` will return a single string concatenated selected text's. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/0b0obyra/6/).

Because `:selected` is returning multiple elements, you'll want to loop through them, and do something with *each*. One way of doing this is using [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

You'll need to create a new `option` for each selected one - I've moved a little

```
$("#ProfAdd :selected").each(function (idx, selOpt) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option'); // create new option element
    opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('ProfAdd').value));
    opt.value = $(selOpt).text(); // set value property of opt
    opt.text = $(selOpt).text();
    sel.appendChild(opt); // add opt to end of select box (sel)
    $(selOpt).remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/0b0obyra/5/

The code still isn't ideal - you're mixing `document.getElementById` (vanilla JS) with `$('#id')` (jQuery). Pick one and stick to it.

Here's a much cleaner solution...

```
var $multiSel = $('#ProfAdd');
var $singleSel = $('#selProf');
$('#button6').click(function(){
    var $opts = $singleSel.find('option:selected');
    $multiSel.append($opts).val('');
});
$('#button7').click(function(){
    var $opts = $multiSel.find('option:selected');
    $singleSel.append($opts).val('');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/0b0obyra/8/